# AngularJS - How to change another image when principal image change

Tags: angularjs, image

I'm trying to develop a solution through AngularJS where when the user changes the profile image, all other photos based on their profile are also changed.

[image: Chat]

How can I start developing this feature?

Thanks in advance!

**[Solution]**

With the help of the @wolfman6377, I can understand the functionality and develop the solution for what I need. I'll leave an example in CodePen.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eWZgOp)

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('myController', function() {
        this.myVar = 'https://robohash.org/asd'
        this.updatePicture = function() {
            this.myVar = 'https://angular.io/resources/images/logos/angular/angular.png';
        };
});
```

Thank you, @wolfman6377.

Comment: it's not at all clear what your problem is here.  Your code is a mess.  You have no angular app or controller, are trying to use `ng-init` for a purpose it isn't meant for, and are trying to use jquery to change the `ng-init` value on click, but the `ng-init` value is only processed once, when the page loads.  You should spend some more time studying how angular is designed, and don't even load jquery on an angular page at all unless you have **absolutely no other option**.

Comment: @Claies See the response of "wolfman6377"... He wants to help, you not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a jQuery-like strategy. jQuery element selector will not be able to change the value of myVar.

I would recommend going through some basic tutorials on angular1. But in a nutshell, you need to:

1. Do not grab elements and change attributes
2. add a module to the `ng-app` value
3. Use ng-controller in the template
4. Add ng-click to the button to update the value of `myVar`

template

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div id="var" ng-controller="myController as vm">
        <img ng-src={{vm.myVar}} />
        <button ng-click="vm.updatePicture()">Click me</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

controller:

```
angular
    .module('myApp', [])
    .controller('myController', function() {
        this.myVar = 'https://www.w3schools.com/angular/pic_angular.jpg'
        this.updatePicture = function() {
            this.myVar = 'https://angular.io/resources/images/logos/angular/angular.png';
        };
    });
```